# My boss reprimanded me for taking our scheduled call from the car.

Tags: professionalism, communication

I had a 1-on-1 call (monthly, but my boss tends to slips dates and constantly shift them around). The call was scheduled between 17:00 and 17:30; I left the office 10 minutes before 17, called in exactly at 17:00, from my car, using headphones (I was alone in the car and driving home, a well known route, no need to follow a GPS). My manager refused to continue the call because he claimed I could not be "focused" and he could not look at him in the eyes; he pointed out my lack of "respect" and organisation. My points (not accepted) were:

- We take customers calls from our cars all the time (we are consultants, often on the road)
- My working hours are 9-17, and I often work evenings (and travelling, I am away weeks in a row)
- I can totally focus on the call while driving, in fact, we argued for 30 minutes before hanging up.

At first he mentioned taking this up from HR, then retracted it. I think I was right in taking the call from the car, and I don't think my behaviour was unprofessional. I'd like to hear different opinions though.

Comment: Unfortunately this question will likely get closed since it is unanswerable, except with opinions. In my opinion, you had a meeting scheduled, and you should have pre-arranged with your boss that you would attend the meeting via phone. Unfortunately, just because the boss is unprofessional by shifting meetings around all the time, doesn't excuse your lack of professionalism in this case. Sorry.

Comment: So the call was scheduled for after normal working hours and he was insulted you took it in a car.  He is a jerk.  Has he gone off on other stuff like that?  How hard can it be to have phone call and drive?

Comment: Maybe you could focus on the call, but you couldn't simultaneously focus on your driving.  You aren't justified in talking on a phone while driving.  You are endangering everyone else on the road.

Comment: It was a call, and nowhere specified it had to be with cameras on. Moreover, handsfree are legal in most countries and I was using one; I'm in sales and it's common to take customer's calls in cars. But I appreciate everyone's comment and I have to take part of the blame; I'm going to be more careful in the future and if a call/facetime is scheduled outside working hours, I'll make sure to compensate with time off.

Comment: "he pointed out my lack of "respect" " - are you working as a samurai? Or in the mafia?? This is no way for professional adults to talk...

Comment: @AakashM - i've called out on one of my subordinates being disrespectful  in this case, it was because he kept interrupting me.

Comment: FYI, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phones_and_driving_safety#Handsfree_device has references to a number of studies regarding the use of hands-free mobile phones while driving.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a difference between taking a quick call to confirm a specific detail or "touch base" with someone, and a sustained 30-minute one-on-one which requires you to report on activity and respond to questions needing detailed answers.

Sorry - despite the fact that everyone behind the wheel thinks they are simply better than everyone else out there, and despite what everyone thinks about their multi-tasking abilities - the science really does show that people's attention to driving is severely curtailed by the mental processing needed by the type one-on-one call you'd have undertaken.

Was your boss' reaction over the top? Yes - elevating straight to HR was pretty much over the top, but he backed down, so that's deal with.

Was your boss right to cancel the call? Yes - if you had a scheduled call, and you didn't want to be at the office when it came in, you could have asked to reschedule it.

Comment: Thanks, I accept it as a proper answer. Thinking with a cooler head, he probably was right but over the top, so I'll just suck it up and adjust my behaviour. Lesson learned, thanks all.